# Triggering validation of <rich:calendar> client side?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a rich:calendar on a jsf page like this:

```
<rich:calendar id="someDate"
  name="aName" validatorMessage="wrong format!"
  enableManualInput="true" datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
  value="#{MyBean.someDate}" >
</rich:calendar>

<rich:message id="validationSomeDate" for="someDate"
   tooltip="false" showDetail="false">
  <f:facet name="errorMarker">
    <h:graphicImage id="imgError" value"/someImage.gif" />
  </f:facet>
</rich:message>
<rich:tooltip for="validationSomeDate" value="wrong format!"/>
```

This succesfully validates that the user didn't write some nonsense into the date field like "12456" or something. The problem is, this validation is only triggered when the form is submitted. I would like to have this checked as soon as the date field loses focus, all client-side. Is there a way to do this?
I tried using a

```
<rich:validator>
```

tag but I'm using richfaces 3.x and this tag isn't available.

```
<rich:ajaxValidator event="onblur">
```

doesn't help either...

Comment: Try `oninputblur`, RF3 calendar doesn't have `onblur`.

Comment: You could also use the `onchange`. `onblur` will trigger a validation per keystroke